# Htaccess only works for http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.tdl$
RewriteRule !^MySubFolder /MySubFolder%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Why does this rewirte condition only works for http and not for https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of mod_rewrite requires at a minimum "AllowOverride FileInfo" to be set on the document root for it to act.

Check your config for SSL (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf by default), ensure that it looks something like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

The default for AllowOverride is 'None', so any other setting (such as 'All') which adds FileInfo capabilities is OK.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Additional information on this answer can be found here: [Why do .htaccess redirects work in http but not with https?](https://serverfault.com/a/226912/268042)
From there I have the possible answer for your question.